Sock Bind error in Apache Functions Python in local
I'm testing Apache Functions and I'm trying to test my function locally
For this, I have started the local server with
fn start --log-level DEBUG --port 8080

and I'm trying to create, deploy and invoke a test function with
fn use context default
fn update context registry mylocalregistry

fn -v init --runtime python fn-local

cd fn-local

fn -v deploy --create-app --app app-local --local
fn invoke app-local fn-local

But the invocation (last line) fails with Error invoking function. status: 502 message: Container failed to initialize, please ensure you are using the latest fdk and check the logs
In the server logs I see that the problem is a python socket creation
...
time="2024-12-21T19:48:40Z" level=debug msg="  File \"/python/fdk/__init__.py\", line 62, in start\n" app_id=01JFN9NJFZNG8G00GZJ0000001 container_id=01JFNC7J7ZNG8G00GZJ0000003 fn_id=01JFNC6GG1NG8G00GZJ0000001 image="mylocalregistry/fn-local:0.0.2" tag=stderr
time="2024-12-21T19:48:40Z" level=debug msg="    sock.bind(phony_socket_path)\n" app_id=01JFN9NJFZNG8G00GZJ0000001 container_id=01JFNC7J7ZNG8G00GZJ0000003 fn_id=01JFNC6GG1NG8G00GZJ0000001 image="mylocalregistry/fn-local:0.0.2" tag=stderr
time="2024-12-21T19:48:40Z" level=debug msg="PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted\n" app_id=01JFN9NJFZNG8G00GZJ0000001 container_id=01JFNC7J7ZNG8G00GZJ0000003 fn_id=01JFNC6GG1NG8G00GZJ0000001 image="mylocalregistry/fn-local:0.0.2" tag=stderr
time="2024-12-21T19:48:40Z" level=info msg="hot function terminated" app_id=01JFN9NJFZNG8G00GZJ0000001 container_id=01JFNC7J7ZNG8G00GZJ0000003 cpus= error="container exit code 1" fn_id=01JFNC6GG1NG8G00GZJ0000001 idle_timeout=30 image="mylocalregistry/fn-local:0.0.2" memory=256

...

I have already tried to run the starting with root  sudo fn start with no change
I'm using Mac Sequioa with Rancher
